# MP3 file with zeros before 0xfffb

Tags: mp3

I stumbled on a mp3 file with a bunch of zeros before the usual `0xfffb`.  In fact, the mp3 audio data starts at offset `0x414`.  The file plays well.

What do all those zeros mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They really don't "mean" anything...  From the offset, I would guess the zeros are placeholders for an ID3v2 tag that was never written.  A MP3 decoder will ignore them.

Comment: According to this http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_header the header should be only 10 bytes.  What the `0x414` offset means to you?

Comment: The ID3v2 tag's _header_ is only 10 bytes, but the tag itself (which is *not* a header for the file) is much larger. The encoder left room for 1034 bytes of ID3v2 data, but probably didn't need it, hence the 1044 '0' bytes at the beginning of the file.